# Automatically selecting ROI after the target object is detected once in live video and if it loses track of it then search again in that ROI only

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision, eye-detection

I'm working on a project that detects eyes of the person in the sight of camera. I have used face_cascade and eye_cascade to determine it. It works fine with adjustable threshold. But if for some reason the whole face can not be detected after a while, the eye detection stops. For example if the eyes are detected once but now the person wears a helmet, though eyes are still visible but it becomes difficult to detect eyes without detecting the face first.

*Can you please help and guide me on how the program can automatically search for eyes by setting up an ROI there once it has detected them earlier?*

*If that's not possible, then how to manually select ROI so that program looks for those particular areas only?*

**Thanks in advance**

Code reference:

```
def main():
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
time.sleep(1.000)
cv2.namedWindow('image')
cv2.createTrackbar('threshold', 'image', 0, 255, nothing)
while True:
    _, frame = cap.read()
    face_frame = detect_faces(frame, face_cascade)
    if face_frame is not None:
        eyes = detect_eyes(face_frame, eye_cascade)
        for eye in eyes:
            if eye is not None:
                threshold = cv2.getTrackbarPos('threshold', 'image')
                eye = cut_eyebrows(eye)
                keypoints = blob_process(eye, threshold, detector)
                eye = cv2.drawKeypoints(eye, keypoints, eye, (0, 0, 255), cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)
    cv2.imshow('image', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: can you share a picture when you are not getting the right eyes detection properly?

Comment: @RoyAmoial Its not an issue of wrong detection. It took me about 7 mins of calibration of threshold to get my eyes partially detected(detection with the spot blinking as if the program is trying again and losing track again) while wearing a helmet. It took me less than 30s to calibrate for same lighting conditions without helmet. Since the use requires changing lighting conditions, hence I want the detection to be fast by reducing the roi once first time detection is complete.

Comment: I am trying to find better libary and methods for you to detect the faces and the eyes even with helmets and stuff like that. if you could share a picture with the person wearing the helmet (when face isn't detected) it will be great.

Comment: @RoyAmoial Here take this example of a stock photo: https://imgur.com/GqaCcm2 . The program should have detected the eyes as they were clearly visible. So after one detection if ROI was fixed then I think this would have been identified.